# C#, Type.GetType() not returning class name from string in all cases

Tags: c#, class, reflection, activator, gettype

My code is like this

```
public static object getClassInstance(string key, params  object[] constructorArgs)
        {
            string assemblyPath = null;
            string customClassName = null;
            DataSet objDataset = getAssemblyInfo(key);
            if (objDataset != null && objDataset.Tables.Count > 0 && objDataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                assemblyPath = objDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ACA_ASSEMBLY_PATH"].ToString();
                customClassName = objDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ACA_CLASS_NAME"].ToString();
            }

            Assembly assembly;
            Type type;

            if (assemblyPath != null && assemblyPath != string.Empty)
            {
                assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
                type = assembly.GetType(customClassName);
            }
            else // if no customisation
            {
                type = Type.GetType(key);
            }

            object classInstance = constructorArgs == null ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) : Activator.CreateInstance(type, constructorArgs);
            if (classInstance == null) throw new Exception("broke");
            return classInstance;

        }
```

In my above code i am passing a key as namespace-qualified  . // if no customization section of the code was working perfectly alright for some days . then suddenly it started acting wiered . it returns me class name from string in some cases and in some cases it wont(returns null) . All the class names to be generated from the key have access from this method . There is no accessibility issue as such.

I saw a documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx . 
In the remarks section it tells

GetType only works on assemblies loaded from disk. If you call GetType to look up a type defined in a dynamic assembly defined using the System.Reflection.Emit services, you might get inconsistent behavior. The behavior depends on whether the dynamic assembly is persistent, that is, created using the RunAndSave or Save access modes of the System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess enumeration. If the dynamic assembly is persistent and has been written to disk before GetType is called, the loader finds the saved assembly on disk, loads that assembly, and retrieves the type from that assembly. If the assembly has not been saved to disk when GetType is called, the method returns Nothing. GetType does not understand transient dynamic assemblies; therefore, calling GetType to retrieve a type in a transient dynamic assembly returns Nothing.

Is that some thing causing me the problem? . Can anyone help .

Comment: So what changed after those few days when it was working?

Comment: Now, verify what kinda classes your assembly loads up using Assembly.LoadFile method. I mean do those classes has nested classes as well?

Comment: hmmm.. Actually we can't read messages in your gmail inbox. Your link is incorrect.

Comment: @ zenwalker  Assembly.LoadFile loads assembly correctly . problem is in else part . wen i don have an custom assembly i have to load my default class . thats where the problem is .

Comment: @Andrey Shvydky sorry , i updated the link

Comment: @ slugster i reverted all wat i changed back  to the same old form ,its still the same